# jQuery Get() to WebMethod not working

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

I'm trying to call the jQuery function `$.get()` to make a call to my `WebMethod` but it's only hitting the `Page_Load` event in the code behind. I can see the request being sent out in firebug to `/admin/manage-users.aspx/deleteUser?u=user1` but it never hits the WebMethod.

jquery

```
$('#delete').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var userName = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.userName').text();
        $.get('/admin/manage-users.aspx/deleteUser', { u: userName });
    });
});
```

aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public void deleteUser() {
    string userName = Request.QueryString["u"];
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) {
        if(Membership.DeleteUser(userName))
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I gave credit to bugz below because he pointed me in the right direction.

> In order for your `[WebMethod]` to work your method within the aspx has to be static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link for more information

[More Information](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

```
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "'/admin/manage-users.aspx/deleteUser'",
                    data: "{'userName ' : '" + userName + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
        //do something on success

                    },
                    error: function(ex) {
       //do something on failure

                    }
                });
```

Also on success if you are returning data or a variable make sure you use data.d for some reason when using jquery/ajax microsoft wants the .d at the end of the variable. This took me time to figure out.

Try this Im guessing when you debug the deleteUser Method never gets called.

```
var jqxhr = $.get("admin/manage-users.aspx/deleteUser",  { userName: userName }  function() {
    alert("success");
  })
  .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
  .error(function() { alert("error"); })
  .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: thanks for the response bugz, but this doesn't really address my question. I understand that ajax() gives me more flexibility but I'm just doing a simple GET, get() *should* work

Comment: hmmm im guessing your break points on deleteuser never get called how about trying to breakpoint on a success or error event and see whats happening

Comment: good idea. I'm working on some other stuff today so it may be a day or two before I can get back to this project. I'll check back in when look into your suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: ok had a quick chance to look at it. It's throwing a 500, unknown web method

Comment: I figured it out. My webmethod **needs** to be static, after that it was just a matter of deciding if I wanted to go with a POST or GET. I ended up going the `$.ajax()` route with a POST. Thanks for your help, you really pointed me in the right direction.